# Microsoft Access - Combo Box saves key to table, not names

Tags: ms-access

Well needing a bit of help here...

Instead of explaining the entire situation, I will give an example.

Two tables. Table1 has StudentID and Name. Table2 has StudentID and Name as well. Both tables have StudentID as a key.

I have created a form which has a combo box where the combo box is meant to get the values from Table1's Name and input them into Table2's Name. Though every time I check the table after I have filled the form out, it puts the StudentID instead in the Name box into Table2's Name column. What is weird is that the form shows the drop down of names, but when selected and go to Table2, it just inputs the StudentID instead.

Any help would be thanked. Pretty bad at making situations but I was hoping the issue wasn't too much of an issue.

NOTE: This was all made with the Combo Box Wizard.

**Form**
[image: Form]

**Table1**
[image: Table1]

**Table2**
[image: Table2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the properties of the combobox you should set `Bound Column` on the Data-tab to 2 (assuming that Last Name is the second column in the `Row Source` of the combobox)

Comment: Thank you very much! So simple yet I didn't see it. Thank you again!

Comment: @user2399871 notice, too, that the Column widths probabyl said like `0";1"` and the Row Source was like "Select StudentID, LastName from ...`. When Bound Column = 1 but column 1 is hidden StudentID is still used but only LastName is shown. You could have also solved this by changing your query, to not select StudentID or to rearrange the columns.